# can async with fetch poll until a condition is met? (survive rejection)

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch, es6-promise

Using fetch API and async/await, is it possible to continue polling indefinitely, regardless of availability of a URL? I anticipate that a URL might become available eventually, so I want to keep trying until a condition is met. Tried to come up with a minimum viable code sample and I'm not sure I pulled it off:

```
// this is just a placeholder. It will eventually be a function 
// that evaluates something real. 
// Assume validContinue gets updated elsewhere.      
function shouldContinue() {
    return validContinue;
}
      
async function wonderPoll(someUrl) {

  // just a delay mechanism
  function wait(ms = 1000) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
  }

  // the actual individual poll
  async function pollingFunction(url) {

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      cache: 'no-store'
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      return response;
    } else {
      Promise.reject(response);
    }

  }

  // allegedly keep polling until condition is met. 
  // But the rejected Promise is breaking out!
  while (shouldContinue()) {
    await wait();
    result = await pollingFunction(someUrl);
  }
  
  // when the fetch hits a rejected state, we never get here!
  console.log('done with the while loop, returning last successful result')

  return result;
}

const sampleUrl = 'https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/country.json?ip=8.8.8.8';
const sampleUrl2 = 'http://totallybroken_fo_sho';

// swap the URL to test
wonderPoll(sampleUrl)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log('got a result', result)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('got an error', err)
  });
```

I see what's happening (I think). The parent call ultimately executes the polling function, which rejects on the Promise. The condition to continue is still theoretically met, but the rejection breaks out of the While loop and sends to rejection directly up. This propagates all the way up to the catch method of the original/initial Promise. It doesn't even hit any code that would have come after the While loop in the case of resolved Promises.

What I don't know is how to prevent that from happening. I think I don't understand the syntax for intercepting and resolving the promise. When I replace Promise.reject in the response parser with `Promise.resolve(response)`, it still ends up rejecting up to the top.

If the URL I provide is valid, it will continue until the condition is no longer met.

---

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gregpettit/qf495bjm/5/

To use the fiddle, the "stop" button simulates the condition being met, and I've provided two different URLs that have to be manually swapped (by passing someUrl or someUrl2) to test.

Expected results:

- with good URL, continuous polling (will have to dig into network in dev tools) until condition is met (by pressing Stop!) and then the calling function's 'then' can show the result.
- with bad URL, continuous polling until condition is met, and then calling function's 'catch' shows the error

Actual results:

- positive test case is OK
- negative test case goes directly to the catch

Comment: I have considered just wrapping up a standard XMLHttpRequest with a Promise and explicitly resolving or intentionally NOT rejecting (on error)... it might be that fetch is too terse and inflexible for my needs?

Comment: I would always resolve with some sort of indication of success/failure in the resolved value ... then when "condition is met", return if successful, reject (throw) if failure

Comment: what does `Promise.reject(response);` do since you're throwing away the return value?

Comment: Ron, I'm new to some of this, so it's possible you've caught me in a gaffe. I'd never put it past me. But my understanding is this: the fetch API actually treats coded "errors" as resolutions rather than rejections. But the response's "ok" property is false. So, I'm attempting to accommodate that as well. I could've done it wrong. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code in while loop to try/catch so you can catch the error

result can hold a value when there's no error, or a reason when there is an error

Once the loop is stopped, you either return the value, or throw with the reason

As below

```
async function wonderPoll(someUrl) {

  // just a delay mechanism
  function wait(ms = 1000) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
  }

  // the actual individual poll
  async function pollingFunction(url) {

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      cache: 'no-store'
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      return response;
    } else {
      Promise.reject(response);
    }

  }

  // allegedly keep polling until condition is met. But the rejected Promise is breaking out!
  while (shouldContinue()) {
    try {
      await wait();
      const value = await pollingFunction(someUrl);
      result = {value};
    } catch (reason) {
      result = {reason};
    }
  }
  // when the fetch hits a rejected state, we never get here!
  console.log('done with the while loop, returning last successful result')
  if (result.reason) {
    throw result.reason;
  }
  return result.value;
}
```

Running example https://jsfiddle.net/twkbo9pg/

the example includes `status` in the result, but that is unnecessary (I borrowed code from my `Promise.allSettled` polyfill and forgot to remove that property)

Comment: Makes sense. I also liked your shortcuts for casting/wrapping the values and reasons... not gonna lie, I've never done it like that before.

Comment: it's just ES6 shorthand for `result = {value:value}`

Comment: I am only recently upgrading my skillset... I spent a good long time in ES5-land and didn't have daily bandwidth to get with the times. But those days have arrived. Only took a day to get over my initial (and irrational) dislike of arrow functions. ;-) This worked in the production code, by the way. Which is actually nested inside a few other promises. I will be able to go to bed at a reasonable hour tonight! Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You can `try…catch` it to prevent breaking out of loop.

```js
while (shouldContinue()) {
  try {
    await wait();
    result = await pollingFunction(someUrl);
  } catch (e) {}
}
```

Comment: Tried it out. As simple as it gets! Per Jaromanda X's sample, I think sending the reason for rejection is a nice-to-have, but this definitely fits the bill of "ignore the rejection and continue" and was easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to check out observable streams! If you're going to have a lot of data coming in over time, that's rxjs's whole thing.

There's actually a few ways to do this if this feels janky (it kinda does haha).

```
import { ajax } from "rxjs/ajax";
import { duration } from "moment-timezone"; // I copied this from some old code... whatever.
import { catchError, map, share, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";

const baseUrl = "http://foo.bar"
const base = (method, headers = {}) => ({
  method,
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    ...headers,
  },
  crossDomain: true,
  withCredentials: true,
})

const ajaxGet = url => ajax({ ...base("GET"), url })

export const userEpic = timer(0, duration(5, "minutes").asMilliseconds()).pipe(
  switchMap(() =>
    ajaxGet(`${baseUrl}/users`).pipe(
      map(({ response }) => getUsersSuccess(response)),
      catchError(e => of(getUsersError(e))),
    )
  ),
  share()
)
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. I will put this in my back pocket and investigate rxjs for my future needs! Present-tense Greg has to get this done ideally tonight. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Two things

```js
 } else {
            Promise.reject(response);
        }
```

should return that. It's working "by accident" right now.

```js
 } else {
            return Promise.reject(response);
        }
```

Secondly, `result = await pollingFunction(someUrl);` might want to add .catch to it:
`result = await pollingFunction(someUrl).catch(_=>null);` or whatever can be tested for in the enclosing `while`

But I think you can simplify the whole thing thus:

```js
export async function wonderPoll(someUrl) {
    while (shouldContinue()) {
        await wait();

        const response = await fetch(someUrl, { cache: 'no-store' });

        if (response.ok)
            return response;
    }
    return Promise.reject(); // only if !shouldContinue()
}
```

Comment: Alas, I could not get this working. Here was an attempt to make a fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/gregpettit/cwskm3hf/3/