# Is there a way to use Await to wait until a condition returns true?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I was working on something, and I was thinking about if I could use await() to wait until a condition returns true. Possibly something like this:
`await(x===true);`

I don't know if you can do this, but it would be very helpful if you could!
Is this possible, or no?
Thank you!

Comment: JS doesn't work this way

Comment: see: [Polling until getting specific result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208031/polling-until-getting-specific-result) or [Promise to async await when polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57213034/promise-to-async-await-when-polling) or [can async with fetch poll until a condition is met?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64130475/can-async-with-fetch-poll-until-a-condition-is-met-survive-rejection)

Comment: And linked article in duplicate [Polling with async/await](https://dev.to/jakubkoci/polling-with-async-await-25p4)

Comment: Do you really want to block the main thread until that condition becomes true? In most cases, the answer should be no; instead, create and fire an event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement a busy wait like this:

```js
console.log('begin');

async function busyWait(test) {
  const delayMs = 500;
  while(!test()) await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delayMs));
}

let a = 'hello';
setTimeout(() => a = 'world', 2000);

(async () => {
  await busyWait(() => a==='world')
  console.log('done');
})();
```

Comment: You can, but you absolutely shouldn't.

Comment: why shouldn't you?

Comment: @CerricLiadon It would be much better to subscribe to a certain event, and to create a mechanism that fires the event when something changes.

Comment: @CerricLiadon you should invert the question and ask why you would need to do something like this in the first place? It is incredibly rare to have a valid use case for doing it so and in that virtually non-existent scenario something else is usually dreadfully wrong.